# Fill down data frame in R with date and numeric values

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks this way

```
df <- tibble(date = c('6/8/2021 18:58',
                '6/8/2021 19:00',
                '6/8/2021 19:05',
                '6/8/2021 19:07'), 
       values = c(1,0,1,0)
       )
```

| date | values |
| --- | --- |
| 6/8/2021 18:58 | 1 |
| 6/8/2021 19:00 | 0 |
| 6/8/2021 19:05 | 1 |
| 6/8/2021 19:07 | 0 |

That I need to be transformed to look like this

| date | values |
| --- | --- |
| 6/8/2021 18:58 | 1 |
| 6/9/2021 18:59 | 1 |
| 6/10/2021 19:00 | 0 |
| 6/11/2021 19:01 | 0 |
| 6/12/2021 19:02 | 0 |
| 6/13/2021 19:03 | 0 |
| 6/14/2021 19:04 | 0 |
| 6/15/2021 19:05 | 1 |
| 6/16/2021 19:06 | 1 |
| 6/17/2021 19:07 | 0 |

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is there any reason why the 1s are replicated twice

Answer (score 1):

Use `complete` to return a `seq`uence of date from the `min` to `max` `by` 1 minute after converting the 'date' column to `POSIXct`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    mutate(date = mdy_hm(date))  %>%
    complete(date = seq(first(date), last(date), by = '1 min'),
          fill = list(values = 0)) %>%
    mutate(date = date + days(row_number() - 1), values = +(values|lag(values)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   date                values
   <dttm>               <int>
 1 2021-06-08 18:58:00      1
 2 2021-06-09 18:59:00      1
 3 2021-06-10 19:00:00      0
 4 2021-06-11 19:01:00      0
 5 2021-06-12 19:02:00      0
 6 2021-06-13 19:03:00      0
 7 2021-06-14 19:04:00      0
 8 2021-06-15 19:05:00      1
 9 2021-06-16 19:06:00      1
10 2021-06-17 19:07:00      0
```

Comment: Wow, I still fail to understand the question and here is the first answer. In the OP's desired output the day in the date changes from line to line. It does not in your answer.

Comment: @Bernhard thanks, didn't notice that change in the expected.  Updated

Comment: I am thinking that there is some typo in the expeted output

Comment: @akrun the expected output is correct. The data is a subset of a power status device that stores event time and the binary '0' or '1' where "1" is power ON and "0" is power OFF. Your solution helped out alot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the base R code like below

```
df <- transform(
  df,
  date = strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
)

dfout <- transform(
  data.frame(Date = with(df, seq(date[1], date[length(date)], by = "1 min"))),
  Values = with(df, values[findInterval(Date, df$date)])
)
```

which gives

```
                  Date Values
1  2021-06-08 18:58:00      1
2  2021-06-08 18:59:00      1
3  2021-06-08 19:00:00      0
4  2021-06-08 19:01:00      0
5  2021-06-08 19:02:00      0
6  2021-06-08 19:03:00      0
7  2021-06-08 19:04:00      0
8  2021-06-08 19:05:00      1
9  2021-06-08 19:06:00      1
10 2021-06-08 19:07:00      0
```